# Cómo se evaluan las expresiones booleanas en .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo este codigo, "emulando" una tabla de verdad donde se toman dos proposiciones (PA y PB), se construye una proposición (PC) enlazando con `&` a la negacion de `PA & PB` y por ultimo se analiza las proposiciones hechas anteriormente:

```
// ...
bool PA = false, PB = true; // Propocision A y B
bool PC = !(!PA & PB); // Se niega el resultado de !A & B
bool PD = PA & PB | ((PA & PB) & PC);
// El resultado de PD es false.
```

Cómo son evaluadas las expresiones booleanas en .NET?

Comment: Donde dice `!(!A & B)` debería ser `!(!PA & PB)`?

Comment: con que valor defines PC ?

Comment: Le asigno el valor a PC al momento de declarar `bool PC = !(!PA & PB);

Comment: cierto no habia visto esa asignacion

Comment: esos operadores son los operadores bitwise, and bitwise y or bitwise, no AND y OR, estas seguro que quieres usar esos operados que comprueban bit a bit el valor?

Comment: Hay diferencia entre & y &&?

Comment: si, mucha. En booleanos, para la mayoria de los casos no la hay, pero en algunos casos puntuales, si la hay.

Comment: Oh, no sabía, investigaré más sobre esos operadores, gracias!

Comment: Si, el doble && toma atajos en la evaluación pero hace la evaluación lógica correcta, cosas como; `false and X` siempre será `false` así que no evalua la parte de la derecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las expresiones se evaluan de izquierda a derecha respetando los paréntesis

```
bool PA = false, PB = true; 
bool PC = !(!PA & PB); //not (not(false) and true) = false
bool PD = PA & PB | ((PA & PB) & PC); // (false and true) or ((false and true) and false) = false
```

expandiendo la expresión final:

```
D = A & B | ((A & B) & C)
D = false & true | ((false & true) & false)
D = false | ((false & true) & false)
D = false | (false & false)
D = false | false
D = false
```

Comment: en la expresión final, se evalua  A & B,  A & B , & C y finalmente el `|` de ambos resultados

Comment: Entonces, si `PA` es false, `PD` será `false` independientemente del resto de la asignación?

Comment: Esto andaba buscando, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Los operadores lógicos en C# se evalúan igual que en prácticamente todos los lenguajes es decir, de izquierda a derecha con mayor prioridad los & y posteriormente los |. Los paréntesis, como siempre, cambian el orden de evaluación.

Veo una cierta "confusión" de opiniones respecto a los operadores && y ||. Realmente la única diferencia con respecto a & y | es que trabajan en modo "cortocircuito" es decir, no siguen evaluando si se encuentra un valor que finaliza la condición.

Por ejemplo: true | true, evalúa las dos condiciones, sin embargo true || false evalúa sólo la primera, como es un "OR lógico" cualquier valor que comparemos con él siempre será true (true OR X == true) y por tanto no es necesario que se ejecute la segunda condición.

En el caso de && es similar, false & true evalúa las dos condiciones mientras que false && true evalúa sólo la primera (false AND x siempre es false).

Estos operadores son muy importantes para evitar errores, por ejemplo, imaginemos que obj es un objeto con una propiedad lógica Enabled. Si hacemos esto:

```
obj != null & obj.Enabled
```

Nos dará un error cuando obj sea null, porque & evalúa las dos condiciones y la segunda de ellas "obj.Enabled" lanza una excepción del tipo "obj is null".

Sin embargo, si hacemos:

```
obj != null && obj.Enabled
```

No saltará ninguna excepción porque si obj == null, la primera condición es false y por tanto la segunda ni siquiera se evalúa. Nuestro código en ejecución no pasa por ella y por tanto nunca nos saltará la excepción "obj is null".

Sólo una cosa más, en casos en que tenemos una comparación de este tipo con métodos, es conveniente poner primero las que se van a evaluar más rápido, así obtenemos un código más eficiente. Por ejemplo:

```
if (Metodo1() && Metodo2())
```

Si Metodo1 devuelve false, Metodo2 no se ejecuta y por tanto "ahorraremos" el tiempo de ejecución de ese código (por supuesto, si Metodo1 es true se evaluará Metodo2).

Answer (score 0):

**>>bool PC = !(!PA & PB); // Se niega el resultado de !A & B**

Se niega el valor de PA, o sea pasara ser true. 
Luego se evalua con PB en donde el resultado del `&` sera `true` ya que ambos los son y a esa union se la niega. El resultado final sera `false`

Comment: Entonces, en `PD = PA & PB` es `false`, no debería ejecutarse `| ((PA & PB) & PC)` ?

Comment: en realidad no se evalua si usas || si usas solo una | si se evalua

Answer (score 0):

No sé si lo que quieres saber es por qué PD es false. Se me ocurre que al no indicar paréntesis el | se evalúa antes que el &. Entonces como PA es false, lo que esté a la derecha del & no importa. PD es false siempre.